# How can i serve in a different port laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, port, laravel-7

Normally, when I run `php artisan serve` command it opens at localhos:8000 or 127.0.0.1:8000. I want to run 2 projects at a time so I need to know the process of opening another project in different port like 80 or 8080 while running a project at port 8000.

Comment: You might wanna see and try https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html. It's more clear solution than running every other project on a different port.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run another project at the same time you can use a different port giving the port with the command. As your question, I will show port 8080

```
php artisan serve --port=8080
```

You can also select the specific host and the port both by below command

```
php artisan serve --host=localhost --port=8080
```